# How to add "Related Posts" widget for Google Blogger

Tags: blogger

I wanted to Add a "Related Post" in the footer section of Blogger. And also wanted to know detail about xml or html tags used to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add "Related Post" in blogger xml, you must use js to fetch it from feed rss. may this can help you [add related post](https://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-add-related-posts-widget-to.html)

Comment: That method mentioned in your url is not working i had tried it ago. Can you help me or provide any pdf or any resource to create the code to implement it myself.

Comment: may you can add class in post label and catch it
`
$('.post-label').each(function(){
 var label = $(this).text();
});
`
then use feed json, and place in wherever you want

`http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?alt=json-in-script`

Comment: Tell me in brief please.