# How to show all related post from same author in multi author on blogger blogspot blog

Tags: blogger, blogs

**I have a multi author blogger blogspot blog. I have multiple author on blog. i want to know that How to show all related post from same author in multi author on blogger blogspot blog when anyone click one author name show on every post footer.**

Comment: The best way I know is to give any blog author post his/her own label and then use any of the related post codes out there and instead of using the default blog url that is common in most those codes, use the blog url label feed. Then it's just a matter of adding that code to every author post using a label loop code. Sorry not being able to help more but without any piece of code on what you've done so far it's impossible to help...

Comment: Please send any code in js or jquery to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry. This place don't work like that. We help you fix a problem if we know how to fix it, but I don't think anyone here is going to write you some code without getting paid. I tried to send you on one possible path. The rest is you that must make the effort, use Google, search for codes/tutorials... In a final helping hand: read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732142/3992860